# How to Remove Unnecessary Packages

Tags: java, uninstall

I had installed OpenJDK 7 Runtime (openjdk-7-jre) and when it was installed, it also accompany with lot of package depends, but when i wanted to remove. it just removed openjdk-7-jre size 800 kb, and not removed all OpenJDK 7 Runtime depends. Actually, it become unnecessary packages.

How should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

If the other packages were installed only as dependencies of `openjdk-7-jre` and you have removed `openjdk-7-jre`, you should be able to remove those now-unnecessary packages with:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

If you want to remove their systemwide configuration files too, run this instead:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
```

Comment: I'm very grateful i have tried but it didn't work well. do you have any solution?

Comment: @obysr When you say it didn't work well, what do you mean? Do you mean that no packages were listed to be removed? Or do you mean that there were errors trying to remove them?

Comment: yes, there's no any packages to be removed.

Comment: @obysr Do you know which packages you want removed?

Comment: i don't know, I installed it with USC automatically and doesn't show any depends.

i checked it with command : apt-cache show openjdk-7-jre | grep Depends but I doubt what package which should remove, cause some package intended relation with other apps

Comment: There are three log files that store information about packages that have been installed: `/var/log/dpkg.log`, `/var/log/apt/history.log`, and `/var/log/apt/term.log`. If possible, please paste the contents of these logs into separate http://paste.ubuntu.com pastebins, then **edit your question** to include links to them (making clear which link is to a pastebin of which file), and also include as precise information as you can about the date (and if possible, time) when you installed `openjdk-7-jre` (since the log files are sorted and labeled by date).

Answer (score 0):

I also suspect that there must be a pile of old applications that I tried but discarded. I have also uploaded many packages that simply did not work on Ubuntu, for example Debian software. You have to remove those downloads manually.

Check this site - http://www.stchman.com/cleanup.html

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get autoclean` does not uninstall anything. It just removes cached package files (i.e., files for *installing* packages, `.deb` files) that are no longer provided by download servers and are thus considered unlikely candidates for future (re)installation.